# Dynamically binding custom directive to ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

my controller has the json for my form then i have a directive that gets repeated to produce the form elements.  based on the 'type' passed to the directive, the directive should know how to render the element.

but i don't know why it's not rendering the form templates properly here but that's a separate issue.

my immediate issue is, i can't seen to pass the ng-model and bind it correctly to the template.

does anyone see my problem?

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('ioProductElement', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    var dropdownTemplate = '<select ng-model="model" ng-options="option.Text for option in data"></select>';
    var textAreaTemplate = '<textarea ng-model="model" class="form-control">{{ data }}</textarea>';
    var radioListTemplate = '<span ng-repeat="item in data.Items"><input ng-model="model" type="radio" name="{{ data.Name }}" ng-checked="item.Selected" /><label>{{ item.ProductLabel }}</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>';

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            type: '=',
            data: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var getTemplate = function (type) {
                var template = '';
                switch (type) {
                    case 'SelectListItem':
                        template = dropdownTemplate;
                        scope.model = _.find(scope.data, {
                            Selected: true
                        });
                        break;
                    case 'TextArea':
                        template = textAreaTemplate;
                        break;
                    case 'RadioList':
                        template = radioListTemplate;
                        break;
                }
                return template;
            };

            element.html(getTemplate(scope.type));
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    };
}]);

myApp.controller('DynamicFormController', function () {
    this.productElement = {};
    this.product = {
        ProductName: 'Online Form',
        Company: 'TEST',
        Data: []
    };
    this.productItems = [{
        ProductLabel: "Status",
        ProductType: "SelectListItem",
        ProductData: [{
            "Text": "Item1",
                "Value": "1",
            Selected: true
        }, {
            "Text": "Item2",
                "Value": "2"
        }]
    }, {
        ProductLabel: "Publication",
        ProductType: "SelectListItem",
        ProductData: [{
            Text: 'Item1',
            Value: '1'
        }, {
            Text: 'Item2',
            Value: '2',
            Selected: true
        }]
    }, {
        ProductLabel: "Caption",
        ProductType: "TextArea",
        ProductData: "this is some data for the textarea"
    }, {
        ProductLabel: "Display Advertising",
        ProductType: "RadioList",
        ProductData: {
            Name: "classifiedAdvertising",
            Items: [{
                Text: 'Full Page',
                Selected: true
            }, {
                Text: '1/2 Page'
            }]
        }
    }, {
        ProductLabel: "Status2",
        ProductType: "SelectListItem",
        ProductData: [{
            "Text": "Item1",
                "Value": "1"
        }, {
            "Text": "Item2",
                "Value": "2"
        }, {
            "Text": "Item3",
                "Value": "3",
            Selected: true
        }]
    }, ];

    this.save = function () {
        this.product.Data = this.productItems;
        console.log('in save', this.product);
    };
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.4.0/lodash.min.js"></script>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-sm-12" ng-app="myApp">
    <br />
    <form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="DynamicFormController as ctrl">
        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.productItems">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ item.ProductLabel }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <io-product-element data-model="ctrl.productElement[item.ProductLabel]" data-type="item.ProductType" data-data="item.ProductData"></io-product-element>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-ng-click="ctrl.save()" value="Submit" />

                 product: {{ ctrl.product | json }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try To add a break statement in the first switch case

```
//[...]
switch (type) {
    case 'SelectListItem':
        template = dropdownTemplate;
        scope.model = _.find(scope.data, {
            Selected: true
        });
        break;
     case 'TextArea':
        template = textAreaTemplate;
        break;
     case 'RadioList':
        template = radioListTemplate;
        break;
}
//[...]
```

Comment: Don't use a code snippet for code that won't run.  Use code formatting instead. It's the curly-brace button.